# how to convert integer data type to char in databricks and concatenate

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a code line in databricks and when I run this code it gives me blank values. Not sure what am I missing here.

```
concat(SF1.ParentId,"-", Cast(Cast(SF1.Task_Number + 1 as int)as char(2))) AS tsk
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the data is of the correct type and has the correct values.

Make sure `ParentId` and `Task_Number` do not contain any NULL values. If either of them is NULL, the entire concatenation may result in a NULL value.

To handle NULL values, use the `COALESCE` function like this:

```sql
CONCAT(COALESCE(SF1.ParentId, ''), '-', Cast(Cast(SF1.Task_Number + 1 as int) as char(2))) AS tsk
```

Also, verify that `ParentId` and `Task_Number` are compatible with the concatenation operation. If the data types are not compatible, unexpected behavior may occur.

**Example**: If `SF1.Task_Number` contains any alphabetic characters, the result will be null values.

You can also try the following command for casting to a string:

```sql
CONCAT(COALESCE(SF1.ParentId, ''), '-', STRING(SF1.Task_Number + 1)) AS tsk
```